# Why the UIScrollViewDelegate is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a viewController called "HaveScrollController", and this is something like this:

```
@interface HaveScrollController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIView *firstView;
    IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
    IBOutlet UIView *thridView;
    IBOutlet UIView *fourthView;
}


@property (retain, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *firstView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *secondView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *thridView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *fourthView;


@end
```

and the .m is something like this:

```
@synthesize scrollView,firstView,secondView,thridView,fourthView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    scrollView.delegate = self;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scroll detected");
}

@end
```

I make all the connection to the IB already. And I wanna to use this controller in my "TestAppController", which is something like this, it don't use IB, and generate the interface using code:

```
@interface TestAppController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    HaveScrollController *scollViewController;
}
```

The .m is something like this in the loadView method:

```
scollViewController = [[HaveScrollController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HaveScrollView" bundle:nil];

[mainCanvas addSubview: buttomScollViewController.view];
self.view = mainCanvas;
[mainCanvas release];
```

When I try to scroll the view, but the "scroll detected" is not shown. What did I do wrong? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `scrollView` scrolling at all? It looks like you forgot to set the `contentSize`:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);
```

Obviously, make sure the `contentSize` is larger than `scrollView's` frame so that the scrolling action kicks in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still need to specify a contentSize, though. I don't see anywhere to specify that in IB so you might need to do it in code, in viewDidLoad.