# UIScrollViewDelegate not firing methods

Tags: ios, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a View that has a UIScrollView, with some text (loaded via JSON). I need to detect when the user has reached the end of the scroll (I have seen other questions about it here) but the problem is, i have done the .h implement UIScrollViewDelegate, I have

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
```

in my .h file, and synthezised it in the .m file. I have this in my viewDidLoad:

```
self.scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
self.scroll.delegate=self;
```

Connections are made in the Interface Builder (the IBOutlet "scroll" with the UIScrollView, and so on).

After that, i fulfill the UITextView with the call to the JSON, and do other stuff not related to the scrollView. I have, then, implemented the method scrollViewDidScroll. But, it is never called. The scroll works fine, lets me go up and down to see the whole text. But, any idea why the method of the protocol is not called?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to alloc and init a new `UIScrollView` instance. When you link it from the IB it is already done. That way you are breaking the link.

By the way, your `scroll` property is defined as `retain`, so

`self.scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];`

is a memory leak.

Comment: Ok, i've commented the line that allocs and init the scroll, and make sure that the IBOutlet is connected in Interface Builder. And, no result.

Comment: So how do you the methods are not called? `NSLog`? Breakpoints?

Comment: Hmmm I just have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518290/why-the-uiscrollviewdelegate-is-not-working maybe i MUST set the contentSize? Despite the UIScrollView is working ok?

Comment: What `UISCrollViewDelegate` methods are you implementing?. If the content is not larger than the scroll view itself, they might haven't been called at all.

Comment: Only scrollViewDidScroll. I calculate there if the user reached the end of the scroll. And yes, the content is way larger then the scroll view. Lorem Ipsum stuff :). The solution is that you must set the contentSize in code if you want that method called. Cool Apple fun!</ironic>

Answer (score 1):

Does your `UIViewController`complies with the `UISrollViewDelegate`? The protocol [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

Keep in mind the following:

> The methods declared by the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol allow the
> adopting delegate to respond to messages from the UIScrollView class
> and thus respond to, and in some affect, operations such as scrolling,
> zooming, deceleration of scrolled content, and scrolling animations.

There are not mandatory methods, but you need to adopt the protocol in order to use the methods.

Comment: not all methods are mandatory, as far as i know, i don't have to implement them all.

Comment: The protocol is in my .h file, if that is what you mean: @interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> (it was since the begginig)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Then check frowing comment, that might be the issue.

Comment: Hmm frowing? What do you mean? :P My english is not perfect, and no word like that is in the dictionary :P And i don't think you mean frowning hehe

Comment: Oh you mean the user frowing hehe sorry. Didn't saw his name.

Answer (score 1):

That is... I MUST set programatically the contentSize (despite the scroll is done nicely) if you want the method scrollViewDidScroll get called.

Fantastic... x(

Comment: Well, if the `scroll.frame.size` is the same as the `scroll.contentSize`, what's the point of scrolling? :)

Comment: No need for that kind of comments.